# Python serial port listener

Tags: python, serial-port, interrupt, pyserial

I've begun writing some code using PySerial to send and receive data to a serial device.

Up until now I've only been working on initiating a transaction from a terminal and receiving a response from the serial device.

pseudo:

```
main:
    loop:
        message = get_message()
        send_to_serial(message)
        time_delay(1 second)
        read_response()
```

Now I'd like to implement a listener on that port in the case that the serial device is the one initiating the communication. Also to remove the `time_delay` which could end up way too long, or not long enough for the serial device to respond.

```
state = idle
register_interrupt(serial_device, read_response())

main:
    loop:
        message = get_message()
        state = sending
        send_to_serial(message)
```

So far I haven't found any PySerial code that uses an interrupt to communicate.

I just have no idea how to set up an interrupt of any sort in python, how would

Answer (score 7):

It is possible to use the `select` module to select on a `serial` connection:

```
import serial
import select

timeout = 10
conn = serial.Serial(serial_name, baud_rate, timeout=0)
read,_,_ = select.select([conn], [], [], timeout)
read_data = conn.read(0x100)
```

Below is a full example that creates a pseudo-tty in the main thread. The main thread writes data to the pty in 5 second intervals. A child thread is created that attempts uses `select.select` to wait for reading data, as well as using the normal `serial.Serial.read` method to read data from the pty:

```
#!/bin/bash

import os
import pty
import select
import serial
import threading
import time

def out(msg):
    print(msg, flush=True)

# child process
def serial_select():
    time.sleep(1)

    out("CHILD THREAD: connecting to serial {}".format(serial_name))
    conn = serial.Serial(serial_name, timeout=0)
    conn.nonblocking()

    out("CHILD THREAD: selecting on serial connection")
    avail_read, avail_write, avail_error = select.select([conn],[],[], 7)
    out("CHILD THREAD: selected!")

    output = conn.read(0x100)
    out("CHILD THREAD: output was {!r}".format(output))

    out("CHILD THREAD: normal read serial connection, set timeout to 7")
    conn.timeout = 7

    # len("GOODBYE FROM MAIN THREAD") == 24
    # serial.Serial.read will attempt to read NUM bytes for entire
    # duration of the timeout. It will only return once either NUM
    # bytes have been read, OR the timeout has been reached
    output = conn.read(len("GOODBYE FROM MAIN THREAD"))
    out("CHILD THREAD: read data! output was {!r}".format(output))

master, slave = pty.openpty()
serial_name = os.ttyname(slave)

child_thread = threading.Thread(target=serial_select)
child_thread.start()

out("MAIN THREAD: sleeping for 5")
time.sleep(5)

out("MAIN THREAD: writing to serial")
os.write(master, "HELLO FROM MAIN THREAD")

out("MAIN THREAD: sleeping for 5")
time.sleep(5)

out("MAIN THREAD: writing to serial")
os.write(master, "GOODBYE FROM MAIN THREAD")

child_thread.join()
```

PySerial internally uses select on the read method (if you're on a `POSIX` system), using the timeout provided. However, it will attempt to read NUM bytes until NUM bytes total have been read or until the timeout has been reached. This is why the example explicitly reads `len("GOODBYE FROM MAIN THREAD")` (24 bytes) from the pty so that the `conn.read` the call would return immediately instead of waiting for the entire timeout.

**TL;DR** It is possible to use `serial.Serial` connections with `select.select`, which is what, I believe, you are looking for.

Comment: According to my experience, it is good to set a very small timeout on the `serial.Serial` instance, say 1 ms. Depending on the transmitting device, data may arrive a little slower and with a timeout=0 you can end up reading almost byte by byte, hence looping / selecting a lot with a noticeable CPU consumption increment.

Comment: When trying this solution on my environment (Python 2.7.15, with the current version of PySerial as of Dec. 2018), the abbreviated example throws the exception `io.UnsupportedOperation: fileno` on the line with the `select` statement.  It works normally however when I simply use the `read()` method with a timeout of 1 second.  I'm not sure what the problem is, but it seems to me that you can just do a child thread with an infinite loop and a `.read()` with a brief timeout -- and no `select` is needed.

Comment: PS - I tested this approach (child thread, infinite loop with just a `read()`, and a brief timeout) in my own application, and it worked perfectly.